# Prevent expands 'React-select' when click on it

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-select

I'm using the `react-select` library https://react-select.com/home#getting-started. Trying to reduce select to dimensions `width: 90px; height: 23px`. However, when you click on it, select increases. How to set the above parameters so that select has a cay time of `width: 90px; height: 23px`?

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sk7g4x

```
import Select from 'react-select'

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Select options={options} />
    );
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.css-2b097c-container {
  width: 90px;
  height: 23px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.css-yk16xz-control {
  min-height: 23px;
}

.css-1pahdxg-control {
  min-height: 23px;
}

.select__control--is-focused {
  min-height: 23px;
}

.css-tu25sd-control {
  height: 23px;
}

.selectSort .css-aohzbe-control {
  height: 23px;
}

.selectSort .css-1hwfws3 {
  padding: 0;
}

.css-tlfecz-indicatorContainer {
  padding: 0;
}

.css-yk16xz-control {
  height: 23px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the props `classNamePrefix`. If you don't use this, react-select creates dynamic prefix names such as `css-tu25sd-c..` They aren't reliable.

`<Select 
  options={options} 
  classNamePrefix='my-className-prefix' />`

For more props info see: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#props
Edited solution. Try use the `classNamePrefix` props, update your css to match the dynamic css classes and run in your editor.

```
h1, p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.css-2b097c-container {
  width: 90px;
} 

.my-className-prefix-container,
.my-className-prefix__control {
  width: 90px !important;
  height: 3px !important;
}

.my-className-prefix__value-container,
.my-className-prefix__indicator-separator,
.my-className-prefix__dropdown-indicator {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 8px;
}

.my-className-prefix__control--is-focused {
  height: 23px;
}

.select__control--is-focused,
.css-1pahdxg-control {
  min-height: 23px;
}

.my-className-prefix__placeholder,
.my-className-prefix__value-container,
.my-className-prefix__menu {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.css-yk16xz-control {
  min-height: 23px;
  max-height: 23px;
}
```

Comment: Look at my code css. I changed size my select without classNamePrefix. Did you see my codepen? Click on select

Comment: Yes I saw your codepen. The problem is, over time, the classNames starting with `css-tu25sd-whatever` will change and any styles you have applied will break.  The `<classNamePrefix />` works in your codepen and ensures that your classNames remain static, i.e. will not change over time. Perhaps I misunderstood your question. Let me know

Comment: correction. `<classNamePrefix />` should have been written as `classNamePrefix='my-className-prefix'`. It is a prop not a component

Comment: @john_y Normally I was able to reduce the button. The problem is that as select is focused it increases. I don't know which class to give dimensions as select is focused

Comment: I am still not 100% sure I understand. However as you said ".. as select is focused it increases", I imagine you're talking about the options list dimensions? If so,
```.my-className-prefix__menu-list {
  width: 90px;
  height: 23px;
}
```

Comment: Could you help me? I try change containerIndicator; `.my-className-prefix-indicatorContainer {
  padding: 8px 4px;
}` but it doesn't work

Comment: I see you changed `my-className-prefix` to `selectTasksList`. We'll use that for the remaining examples. You want to add some `padding` to `my-className-prefix-indicatorContainer`. Because you changed the props, we use `selectTasksList-indicatorContainer`

In the DOM, I don't see this class. The closest className I see is `css-tlfecz-indicatorContainer`. `css-tlfecz` is dynamic so we shouldn't use this

But, on the same element, I see a className of `selectTasksList__indicator` Add your padding here. It narrows the dropdown icon container. Is this the appearance you want? Let me know

Answer (score -1):

Do you intend to limit the height to 23px? I checked your stackblitz project, and find that the inner div's height is bigger than 23px. React-select provide some  [customization options](https://react-select.com/styles)we can use. Please check my forked version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pmbsvv to verify if it is something you need.

The following code is just a copy of the index.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import "./style.css";
import Select from "react-select";

const options = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
];

const customStyles = {
  control: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    height: 23,
    width: 90,
    minHeight: 23
  }),
  valueContainer: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    paddingTop: 0
  }),
  dropdownIndicator: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    height: 20,
    paddingTop: 0
  })
};
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        options={options}
        styles={customStyles}
        classNamePrefix="my-className-prefix"
      />
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```